# How to show multiple horizontal scroll card views on the same XML page

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

Here in this image I have already managed to attach one horizontal scroll card view I need more two that way down like the one use in Google play store.
Please suggest how to do so .
The images r retrieved from firebase if that is of any relevance.
Current:-

What I --Image 1 image 2image 3image 4 image 5 image 6--

basically what I want to do:-
--Image 1 image 2image 3image 4 image 5 image 6-- 1st row

--Image7 image 8 image 9 image 10image11 image 12-- 2nd row

Comment: there are 2 possible ways Generate dynamic View inside Horizontal Scroll or use Horizontal recycle view with in recycle view.!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RecyclerView and use a CardView inside its View holder. 
[Create a List with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html?hl=en)